# Java not able to delete file on "C:\" drive

Tags: java, windows, file, permissions

I have the following code :

```
public Tester()
{
    try {
        File f4 = new File("C:\\Vase.zip");
        System.out.println(f4.exists());
        f4.delete();
        System.out.println(f4.exists());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it does not delete the file. (*If I place the file in the D drive and then ask it to delete, it works perfectly.*) So I know that it is a permissions thing. I am using eclipse. I ran eclipse in admin mode only [in windows].

The program is able to write and delete other files, but this one alone is not working. Can anyone guide me on how to solve this?

Comment: Replace `e.printStackTrace()` with `throw new RuntimeException(e)` (or have the method `throws IOException` and propagate it up) - that is, let the program die (removing any superfluous outer `try/catch` as well) instead of stuffing it into a print trace which might be buried. After that: does the program die horribly with an Exception?

Comment: Eclipse might be running in admin mode, but you have to remember that running a java program starts a new instance of java.exe. That might not have the admin privilege inherited from the caller app.

Comment: @GeorgeVremescu Whenever I run Eclipse in admin mode, the applications I run from it also have admin privileges. I'vs been notcing that. But anyways, I narrowed it down to this, another part of my code used the file and did not .close() it. Instead of searching my entire program for the error, can I just run some function to force all other inputstreams and such to let go of it?

Comment: It means java should have a log of all streams opened... that would be an interesting idea!

Comment: Don't blame me, if I am wrong, but it looks like the file is open somewhere else.

Comment: The file is defintely open in another stream[yes, in the dearchiver in my program]. But again, can I force all other streams and applications to let go of the file using some function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is open in your archiver.

Or somewhere else.

Or (unlikely but possible) - some process is over, but the system is still holding it on behalf of that process.

1. Close all applications (except Eclipse, of course) and try again.
2. It the 1. doesn't work - try to reboot, open Eclipse and try again.

If that doesn't work - permissions should be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be this occurs Admin rights problem.

Please run your IDE or run your code with command prompt as Admin then it will easily remove file.